# Ionic App not loading location

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

The location for my ionic app in angularjs is not loading the location. It sometimes gets stored into the model and shows up, but when I do a console.log it never shows up. Here is a codepen of the app

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/niKuI?editors=101

```
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.11/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.11/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console.log is being called before the `getCurrentPosition` method completes. I changed the call in `$scope.searchRest` to be as below and it worked correctly and logged out the url to the console.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.url = $scope.url + '&location=' + 
                     position.coords.latitude + ',' + 
                     position.coords.longitude;
        console.log($scope.url);
    )};
}, function(error) {
    alert(error);
});
```

I hope this helps.